# Style the 'choose file' button

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple way to hide the button within a container div so that it is invisible. However, I want the cursor to be a crosshair over the whole thing, but I don't know how to change the cursor so it is a crosshair when it is highlighting it. As you can observe, the cursor switches to its default when the choose file button is hovered. Here is my code, and a link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-elgamal-mk059?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const MyButton = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: crosshair;
`;

const StyledForm = styled.form`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: crosshair;
`;

const StyledInput = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: pink;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyButton>
        <StyledForm>
          <StyledInput type="file" />
        </StyledForm>
      </MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In `StyledInput` you should use `visibility: hidden` instead of `opacity: 0`. according to codesandbox example

Comment: This doesn't work, as I can now no longer click the button to upload files.

Answer (score 0):

A recently updated solution, supported by most current modern browsers is the [::file-selector-button pseudoelement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button).

[Can I Use ?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_file-selector-button)

So that means your code could be changed to:

```
const StyledForm = styled.form`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: crosshair;
  ::file-selector-button {
    cursor: crosshair;
  }
`;
```